# Why is it marked as duplicate?

Tags: discussion

[Did Karna think that it was adharma to not appoint Duryodhana as king of Hastinapura?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/35755/did-karna-think-that-it-was-adharma-to-not-appoint-duryodhana-as-king-of-hastina)

The so called *original* question is nothing as duplicate.

Comment: Questions about site should be posted on [meta]. Main site is only about questions about Hinduism (religion). Meta is for [Hinduism]. There were 4 reopen votes on the question but there was no 5th vote, votes started to expire.

Comment: *Questions about site should be posted on [meta]. Main site is only about questions about Hinduism (religion). Meta is for [Hinduism].* I don't understand this. The question is on meta only.

Comment: Questions about site should be posted on [meta]. Main site is only about questions about Hinduism (religion). Meta is for [Hinduism.se]. It was originally posted on main site and migrated here. That is why I posted that comment. I hope you won't do that again.

Comment: I have cast my reopen vote .. now one more vote is needed for the question to be reopened.

Comment: Instead of saying "so called *original* question is nothing as duplicate", you should try to explain why and how the question is not a duplicate and what have you done to improve your question after it was closed as duplicate, what is asked in the original question and how it doesn't match with what you have asked in your question. -1 for lack of clarity in the question.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma kindly read my full question details. Maybe you will find the clarity.

Comment: Well, if you are saying only "This is not a duplicate", then it is considered a meta rant. If you are posting something on meta, it should be detail. Otherwise, a comment under that question is enough. What is original question, why it should not be closed as duplicate etc., should be written in the question. Meta questions also have standards.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I mean the original question which is under scan has enough clarity. Talking about this meta question, you can flag it if it breaks rule.

Comment: I am asking about this meta question. There is nothing in the body or some explanation in the body why this particular question should be reopened by users. Flagging is not the solution here. It is letting your know that every question even on meta needs some clarity and explanation. You are inviting a discussion from the community. It should be detailed.  But that is missing. If someone wants to answer this meta, what should they answer? Why it is closed or why it is not reopened? Are you interested to know how to make it reopen? What's your question?  Please [edit] your meta question.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I think (I maybe wrong) the users will visit to original question and read the clarity there. Just like some users did. This is why I didn't put any detail.

Comment: That question on main is different. I am asking about this meta question. What are you asking in this meta question? What is the purpose of this meta question? Do you want it to get reopened? Are you asking why and how it is a duplicate? Are you making a statement that is not a duplicate? What is your question here? What should I discuss about this question? Currently, it is a plain statement that your question is not a duplicate. But what is "it"? and there is no question in the body.

Comment: @Vikas it is better to explain why you don't think it as duplicate here itself. That way all will be on same level of understanding without any assumptions on why this should not be duplicate. Again, it is better to hear from you on **why it is not duplicate**. Hope you understand this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

After the recent edits, [your question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/35755/did-karna-think-that-it-was-adharma-to-not-appoint-duryodhana-as-king-of-hastina) is no longer a duplicate of *[After Dhritarashtra, why was Yudhishthira and not Duryodhana considered the next in line to be the king?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7851/after-dhritarashtra-why-was-yudhishthira-and-not-duryodhana-considered-the-next)* and it has been reopened.