# Question regarding Sanskrit stack exchange

Tags: discussion

Sanskrit language is the most important language for sanathana dharma in the sense that most of the scriptures are written in Sanskrit  and **much more**.

> **Sanskrit is the classical language of Indian and the liturgical
>   language of Hinduism**, Buddhism, and Jainism. It is also one of the 22
>   official languages of India. The name Sanskrit means "refined",
>   "consecrated" and "sanctified". It has always been regarded as the
>   'high' language and used mainly for **religious** and scientific
>   discourse [1](https://www.swaminarayan.faith/articles/sanskrit-pronunciation-and-transliteration),[2](https://www.omniglot.com/writing/sanskrit.htm).

From [this](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/749/661) answer, asking questions on Sanskrit language in our main site is off-topic

> We should mark questions related to Sanskrit language as **OFF-topic**

I came to know that Sanskrit stack exchange also exists once up on a time, but discontinued due to some reasons, which I do not know.

But now with the above quoted reasons, I am feeling that there is a necessity for opening a new *sister site* for Hinduism stack exchange, which will be useful for us to discuss questions related to the Sanskrit language.

**Please share your fresh opinions about possibility, merits and demerits of such new Stack exchange site for Sanskrit language only.**

Comment: Sanskrit grammars are off topic for main but related to hinduism means you can ask. Nothing wrong. If they object then let's object mythologies too as there's mythology stack exchange.

Comment: That's wrong reasoning. Sanskrit is a language whereas mythology is present everywhere in our religion. Questions about a language is off-topic. If you object mythology, then you might be asked to understand the scope properly. There are stories everywhere Vedas, Puranas etc., all are stories. They can't be removed from our site. If that happens, our site lose 60% of site's scope.

Comment: Sidenote: The existence (or lack thereof) of another Stack Exchange site where a given question is on-topic has no inherent bearing on whether that question is on-topic on the current site.

Comment: yeah please do propose a sanskrit site. I will be happy to become member of it.

Comment: Related [Area51 Meta Discussion](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27863/142143).

Comment: @Paṇḍyā I also think a discussion about new proposal on a child meta site is off-topic as stated in my answer. Don't you think?

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Well, proposal scope is better to be discussed on Area51 Meta however since Hinduism.SE community would be interested in particular proposal, I think it's fine to discuss here.

Comment: @Paṇḍyā Can we discuss about any proposal on Hinduism Meta because a few I think a few users (OP and one user who voted) and some others? It is not " proposal scope is better to be discussed on Area51 Meta" , it *should be* discussed on Area 51 after starting a proposal.  There is a  process to start a site. Read my answer below. Proposals and discussion- Area 51 discussion. Hinduism Meta is for Hinduism Stack Exchange not about new proposal. It is off-topic here.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99953/sanskrit

Comment: https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1741/question-regarding-sanskrit-stack-exchange#comment7950_1743

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know two attempts has been made for Sanskrit Language Stack Exchange which has been removed due to lack of activity. Following is a screen-shot of the Area51 page on Sanskrit Language from where you can check how definition page had gone.

> [Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvttL.jpg)
> [Page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vV7m.jpg)

The proposal needs enough followers and 10+ voted questions to pass definition phase. Another thing is that if proposal remains inactive for 7 days, it is subjected for closure and deletion eventually. Last time we had nearly achieved number of followers but the proposal failed to get enough voted questions to complete definition page and meanwhile 7 days of inactivity leads closure of proposal.

<sup>By the way, I think one of the obstructions/resistance is that many people prefer to learn Sanskrit through mother tongue rather than English. (This is just my possible opinion)</sup>

One important thing we should keep in mind before starting proposal is that We should have enough mass committed to participate in definition phase and ask well received questions which would be useful to define the scope of community.

[Area51 FAQ](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) states:

> **How do I start a new site?**
>
> ... All we ask is that you have an enthusiastic, committed group of expert users who check in regularly, asking and answering questions.

Some users (including me in 2016-17) just starts proposal and think that *I hope interesting people will find my proposal and the proposal will get success* **BUT** actually the things are revers (I learned in the starting of 2018): We should build enough mass and *after having enough mass we should make the proposal* then only proposal will likely to pass the definition phase.

That's why when you'll try to make a proposal, Stack Exchange will ask:

[image]

> **Q.** Please share your fresh opinions about possibility, merits and demerits of such new Stack exchange site for Sanskrit language only.

There are no demerits, such community will be very useful, also helpful to this community. The only thing we needs to keep in mind is the possibility which is discussed in this answer. Since we want to make a proposal, we first need to gather mass, then make proposal and then invite/draw interested users to follow and vote. Go through [Changes to the Area51 Process V3.0](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27938/142143) to know the criteria.

Comment: Why can't we discuss this on Area 51 discussions? Why Hinduism Meta? Related question on the same topic - [Do meta questions have a quality standard?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1739/5212). It's about questions on our meta. Do we have a scope and standard on meta or can we discuss each and everything regardless of scope? That was the main objective of that question. Looks like there is nothing of that sort.

Comment: The proposal is now [live](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/123261/sanskrit-language?referrer=ZTc1ZDFiODg0M2Q2ZGJiNTJmMTMzOTE5NzY0YjE5NWY2M2FhMjdjZTM0NWZhNzMxNGNlMmVhOTFjMWI2NzhiZQ95NQFUFCaAOe7lj3e8fX3YLSLxqAEjdQbVYOgvEAhD0)! Consider to participate if you're interested. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There was no Sanskrit Stack Exchange. There was only [a proposal](http://web.archive.org/web/20180501160405/https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/109951/sanskrit-language) for a Sanskrit Stack Exchange (actually two, [here's the other one](http://web.archive.org/web/20161207152643/http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/98070/sanskrit-language)). It didn't get enough followers or the questions to move into commitment stage. There is a long process on Stack Exchange to form a new site. For that detail, visit

[How can I propose a new site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76974/357396)

Our site meta is not a correct place to discuss about that question. Sanskrit might be the language in which Hinduism scriptures are written but it is still a language. For a formation of a new site, we should follow a procedure on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/).